# How to create a json file using existing json file as template?

Tags: java, json, swing

I have a json file which is mostly standard for all my work, the only difference is few parameters.

Now I want to know how can I using java use this json file as a template and provide the parameters as input and save the new json file on local directory?

```
 {
    "key" : "HWM_NAME",
    "value" : "PINE_SLS_SVC_CUST_CNTCT"
  }, {
    "key" : "TOPIC",
    "value" : "SLS_SVC_CUST_CNTCT2"
  }, {
    "key" : "SRC_SCHEMA",
    "value" : "party_pkg"
  }, {
    "key" : "SRC_TABLE",
    "value" : "SLS_SVC_CUST_CNTCT"
  }, {
    "key" : "TGT_SCHEMA",
    "value" : "mstrdata_hub"
  }, {
    "key" : "TGT_TABLE",
    "value" : "SLS_SVC_CUST_CNTCT"
  } ]
},
```

So here I wish to just change the Value: "PINE_SLS_SVC_CUST_CNTCT" to some other value that I would take as input from user and give me a new json file with those values.

PS: I am working on Java Swing to create a GUI to get the parameters from the user and provide the json file as output.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBST7.jpg)

this is how GUI looks

Comment: consider text templating engine like [FreeMaker](https://freemarker.apache.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using some JSON Library, for example GSon

Read the values from json

```
List<LinkedTreeMap> values = gson.fromJson(json, ArrayList.class);
...
```

update the values, here you can write values from UI components!!!!

```
for (LinkedTreeMap pair : values) {
            //Update values
            System.out.println(pair.toString());
        }
```

And generate JSON from java objects

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap;

        ...

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(values);
```

Comment: That's not what he was asking for.